# Installing and using the play framework on windows vista with java

Tags: java, playframework, windows-vista

I am brand new to the play framework and could use a little bit of help understanding first why the play framework is useful, and how to install and use it on windows vista. The project that I will be working on will be to make a custom API that will power a photo sharing software to be accessed by mobile and desktop devices. I tried to go through the installation guide on the play website but I couldn't get it to work (unfortunately i'm not very good when it comes to manual installations in the command line on windows).

I would like to be able to run one of the sample projects included, but I am unsure of how to get the play command installed on the command line to run it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunatly the [installation guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Installing) is really easy to follow... Install java, download & extract the binary distribution and `play`

Comment: I have java and downloaded and extracted the binary distribution files but what do you mean by play? do you mean run the play.bat file? cause I do that and it pops up and goes away.

Comment: It says to do a `play help`... the batch needs some arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open a command window then type :

c://pathtoplaydirectory/play

Comment: thanks that worked (like I said I'm not to great with the windows command line lol), but how can I set it so I don't have to to the play files path?

Comment: nm I figured it out, you add the folder location of the play batch file to the classpath and path environment variables, like the website says to lol. Thanks for the help!